# Master-detail datagridviews : RowValidating & CellValidating on details DGV fail to prevent user from leaving invalid cell

Tags: c#, validation, datagridview, master-detail

in my WinForms app. i have master-detail DatagridViews.
i have a RowValidating and CellValidating event handlers on detail grid.

if detail cell/row validation fails, i set e.Cancel to TRUE.
this prevents user from leaving cell/row in details grid, EXCEPT in one case :

when user inserts invalid data in details cell and directly moves focus to a master record which is not its parent, then user is not prevented from leaving that invalid cell !

further more, when i return back to THAT invalid cell, i discover that invalid value wasn't accepted, and cell has its old value.

another case: if i delete cell's value instead of inserting an invalid value, e.Cancel is also set to TRUE because that value is required. i repeat the previous scenario and when i get back to that cell, i find it EMPTY, not even having its old value...

can anyway tell me how to prevent user from leaving invalid detail cell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem using a simple workaround.

In detail grid `CellValidating`, when input is Invalid I do the following:

```
e.Cancel = true;
MessageBox.Show("message to inform user");
```

User will click OK to dismiss the message box, and that is enough to keep focus on the invalid cell in detail grid.

I hope that will help others.